# how to switch between two screens in kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, split-screen-multitasking

I'm trying to switch between two screens.. but it doesn't work.. it didn't show anything or any error I don't know what is the problem, here's my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class mainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class secondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class windowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(mainWindow(name='main'))
sm.add_widget(secondWindow(name='second'))


class multApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multApp().run()
```

and mult.kv

```
windowManager:
    mainWindow:
    secondWindow:

<mainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    Button:
        text: "Submit"
        on_press : root.manager.current = "second"

<secondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    Button:
        text: "go back"
        on_press : root.manager.current = "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code.

- Your `build()` method returns `mainWindow()`. This means that your app GUI consists of just a `Screen` (`mainwindow`) with no `ScreenManager`. So the `root.manager.current =` lines in your `kv` will fail because there is no manager.
- Your `mult.kv` file contains a rule (`windowManager:`) for building the GUI, but this rule is over-ridden by your `build()` method.
- In your code, you have three lines (starting with `sm = ScreenManager()`) that also build the GUI, but you do nothing with the results of these lines. So those lines have no effect.
- Your class names should start with an upper case character. When using `kv`, as you are, this is a requirement.

Taking all this into account, here is a modified version of your code that should work:

python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# sm = ScreenManager()
# sm.add_widget(mainWindow(name='main'))
# sm.add_widget(secondWindow(name='second'))


class multApp(App):
    pass
    # def build(self):
    #     return mainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multApp().run()
```

mult.kv:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    Button:
        text: "Submit"
        on_press : root.manager.current = "second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    Button:
        text: "go back"
        on_press : root.manager.current = "main"
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John's answers, just to add to that. If you are declaring manager as a class I always return manager in the build methods, also its good practice to create ids for  your screens under your root manager, as such will make them easier to reference

```
<WindowManager>:
    id: screen_manager

    MainWindow:

         id: main_window
         name: "main_window"
         manager: screen_manager   

    SecondWindow:

         id: second_window
         name: "second_window"
         manager: screen_manager
```